# In reStructuredText, how does one do an 'inline' include of an external document fragment?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a bullet lists of hyperlinks to articles, where each article has a one-line summary.  And, I would like my one-line summary to appear in the bullet list:

- [Thing1](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thing1): This is a thing.
- [Thing2](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thing2): This is also a thing.

Because (1) my summaries quite involved, (2) I have many articles, and (3) even more bullets, I'd like to put the summaries into their own document fragments and 'include' them in both the bullet list and the article.  But, *this* does not fly in reStructuredText:

```
* `Thing1`_: .. include:: summary-of-thing1.txt
* `Thing1`_: .. include:: summary-of-thing2.txt
```

The text `.. include:: summary-of-thing1.txt` ends up in my generated HTML document, and this appears to be because directives (like `.. include::`) must be in their own 'paragraph' like this:

```
* `Thing1`_:

  .. include: summary-of-thing1.txt
```

But, doing that puts my document fragment into its own paragraph, which makes it look like this:

- [Thing1](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thing1):

  This is a thing.
- [Thing2](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thing2)

  This is also a thing.

When, what I really want is for my summaries to appear on the very same line as my hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see this is what [`.. replace::`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replacement-text) is for.  One can say this:

```
* `Thing1`_: |summary-of-thing1|
* `Thing2`_: |summary-of-thing2|

.. include:: summaries.txt
```

And put the summaries into `summaries.txt` like this:

```
.. |summary-of-thing1| replace:: This is a thing.
.. |summary-of-thing2| replace:: This is also a thing.
```